# find total combinations of 2 different lists with multiple values into 2-tuple

Tags: python, combinations

I wish to find the total combinations from below 2 lists into 2-tuple. I tried to find other resources but could not find the right similar solution.

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

expected output:

```
[(a,1), (a,2), (b,1), (b,7), (a,6) ....] # should be only max with 2-tuple, 2 elements in the tuple
```

is there a way to do so? I found the itertools combinations to have limit but it only does for 1 array and not 2 arrays.

Comment: Your expected output is unclear. Using an ellipsis (the ... ) is only appropriate when the pattern is clear. In this case it isn't. I *think* that you are just looking for `itertools.product(a,v)`.

Comment: Are you sure the expected output is `[(["a", "b", "c", "d"],1), (["a", "b", "c", "d"],2), (b,1)....]` (with whatever `b` and `....` are)?

Comment: My apology. I updated my output. It should be max 2 elements in the tuple with combinations from two different length of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a double loop to do so:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
res = []
for i in a:
    count = 0
    for j in v:
        if count>1:
            break
        res.append((i,j))
        count = count+1


print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('d', 2)]
```

Comment: Sorry and thanks but I think you got me wrong sir. My meaning is maximum of 2 elements in the tuple and not value with max to 2. For example we can get (a,8), (b,7) as long as its 2 maximum elements in the tuple.

Comment: @Joe Confused. So it should be `[('a', 7), ('a', 8),...` Can you give the target output of this example.

Comment: No, I mean, we have 2 different length of different values of lists. I wanted to find the combinations of these 2 lists but limit the elements in the combination for the tuple to be 2 elements. I can go from any alphabets in list a, and also any numeric in list v combinations but the tuple should have only 2 maximum elements. (a-z,1-100) <- example of a-z any alphabets and 1-100 any numeric.

Comment: Can you tell me wts the expected output of this `a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, thanks~

Comment: my expected output is actually the output after i changed your count>1 to count>7.

Comment: That is the output that I want but do you have a better and shorter lines of solution thank you

Comment: its a weird algorithm because v only uses 1,2

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your desired output right, you are trying to do a **cartesian product** of two iterables.
You can easily do this in Python through the **`itertools`** library:

```
import itertools

combinations = itertools.product(a, v)
```

`combinations` is an ordered list of all the binary tuples obtained by combining the elements of the two iterators according to the cartesian product schema.